# <script> tags are not loading in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have upgraded the magento from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.4 by method used in the  [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9) link

After the successful upgrade to 1.9.2.4 all my js stopped working.
when i check in my view source there is not a single js file and nor  single `<script>` tags are loaded on my page.
But my css file and styling are properly loaded.

Following are the list i tried :-

1)Merge JS in backend.

2)Deleted cache.

3)Set proper permission.

Kindly let me know what need to be done to resolve this.

Comment: Don't Merge JS change this setting to **NO** and than tring to delete cache.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of isssue.

Comment: @NewBeeInMagento No luck :(
i hope you got my point. Not a single script is seen in viewsource , nor single js file is been loaded.